# Command-line connect curl to an integer socket opened by my application using socket()

Tags: unix, command-line, curl, libcurl

Basically I have an application that has opened a socket.

e.g.

```
int socket = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Now I want to send an HTTP put request to that socket. I know I should be using libcurl but I just can't get that to work correctly. So I want a way to connect curl to my application.

Maybe something like??

```
curl -X PUT -d @myXmlFile.xml /var/run/myunixsocket
```

Is there no way besides using libcurl??? I can't get it to work or find an example of it actually writing to a socket rather than a URI.

It should go without saying that an HTTP server is listening on the other end of that socket.

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to use UNIX sockets in cURL 7.40 with the addition of a new `--unix-socket` option:

```
curl -X PUT -d @myXmlFile.xml --unix-socket /var/run/myunixsocket
```

Under the hood, it will use the the [`CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH.html) option of libcurl. If you would like to know how to program with libcurl, use the `--libcurl` option:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/myunixsocket http://localhost/ --libcurl example.c
```

The generated file `example.c` will look like:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURLcode ret;
    CURL *hnd;

    hnd = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://host/path");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH, "/var/run/myunixsocket");

    ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

    curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
    hnd = NULL;

    return (int)ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a `ncat` proxy quickly.

#### Terminal A

```
# forward incoming 2375/tcp to unix socket
$ ncat -vlk 2375 -c 'ncat -U /var/run/docker.sock'
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::2375
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:2375
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1.
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1:55539.
```

#### Terminal B

```
# make a tcp request
$ curl http://localhost:2375/images/json
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried grepping the curl source for AF_'s other than AF_INET(6) and found only a couple of references to AF_UNIX, which were in the libcurl part and were mostly technical, assuming that someone "else" fills the sockaddr structure. I'm afraid there's no way to make the curl executable do this directly.

Is it disallowed or undesired in your application to listen on a TCP socket (as an alternative, maybe)? If not, but you are not against listening to one on your machine (with proper access control, of course), you may create one simply as a tunnel to AF_LOCAL... I know this is a terrible workaround but it would work, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that curl has no idea how to communicate with a unix domain socket -- it expects a tcp socket.